# VB.NET How to make a custom system time (real-time)

Tags: vb.net, user-defined-functions, datetime-format, helper

So Im stuck here on my project in VB.Net . I wanted to make a user defined date time function that is not dependent on the system time Ive tried to search on the net but they only gave me how to print current system time. Any idea guys how to make a customized date time updating every seconds in other words real time .

any answers will be entertained thanks in advance.

Comment: "user defined date time function that is not dependent on the system time" - I have no idea what you mean. Please expand your question and include some code of what you have tried so far, otherwise it is likely to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the value of `Date.Now` at the start of your application in a global variable:

```
Public StartDate As Date = Date.Now
```

Then you can calculate the current date in your arbitrary time scale, using the `TimeSpan` calculated from this starting date and the current date, at any point in your code:

```
Dim Elapsed As TimeSpan = Date.Now - StartDate
Dim NewDate As Date = ArbitraryStartDate + Elapsed
```

Choose `ArbitraryStartDate` to be any date you like with the `Date` constructor like

```
Dim ArbitraryStartDate As Date = New Date(1983, 05, 03)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing . Thank you for your response I really appreciated it.

Comment: @RobinBernardo No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. You should however read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve the questions you ask, as this one wasn't entirely clear in the first place.

Comment: Im having trouble in setting the correct timezone. Because im implementing a system that uses time that is not dependent on the computers system time.